# Lat/Long mask positive/negative detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

Hey all I am trying to create a **mask** for my **2 input boxes** that will house the **latitude** and **longitude**.

Taken that the **latitude** can be a **positive or negative number** and the same goes for **longitude**. The issue being is that I am trying to come up with a **regex** that can give the user the ability to **first chose if its going to be a positive or negative number** then g**ive user the mask of (-/+)XXX.XXXXXX**.

**However**, I am not getting too close to the conclusion and so I am asking for a some help in reaching that goal.

I have set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/4w8uvpjz/) of what I have so far, which is not much, in order to archive my goal.

```
$('.mask').inputmask({
    regex: String.raw `^[-/*][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{7}$`
});
```

The above code works for negative numbers but when typing out, say 100., it just sits there because its waiting on the - in order to begin. I thought adding the * it would allow it to input a positive number. The above **should** allow the user to input in the format of **-XXX.XXXXXX** OR **XXX.XXXXXXX**.

I still need to figure out how to also tell when the first part (xxx.) is only 1 or 2 digits instead of 3 which makes the user have to put in a 0's in front of said number digits.

So valid input would be like so:

> -2.984593   instead of -002.984593
>
> -74.192822  instead of -074.192822
>
> -102.738631
>
> > 
>
> 7.653721   instead of +007.653721
>
> 10.746633  instead of +010.746633
>
> 110.938365

How can this be formatted in order to work as I need it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply make the dash optional:

```
^-?\d{3}\.\d{7}$
```

I took the liberty of refactoring your RegEx pattern (`[0-9]` -> `\d`, `[.]` -> `\.`).

As for allowing the first part to be one or two digits, you could use:

```
^-?\d{1,3}\.\d{7}$
```

Comment: Neither of those allow you to type **25**.xxxxxxx or **2**.xxxxxxx without having to put 0's in front of the number (025.xxxxxxx and 002.xxxxxxx)

Comment: The way you worded your question makes it seem as thought that was the desired behavior. If you want to **allow** fewer than three digits before the decimal, see edit.